# cleaning data using mapreduce program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2

i have a data with 30 lines. I am trying to clean the data using mapreduce program. data is cleaning properly , but only one line is displaying out of 30 lines. I guess record reader is not reading line by line here. Could you please check my code and let me know where the problem is. I am new to hadoop .

Data :-

```
 1  Vlan154.DEL-ISP-COR-SWH-002.mantraonline.com (61.95.250.140)  0.460 ms  0.374 ms  0.351 ms
 2  202.56.223.213 (202.56.223.213)  39.718 ms  39.511 ms  39.559 ms
 3  202.56.223.17 (202.56.223.17)  39.714 ms  39.724 ms  39.628 ms
 4  125.21.167.153 (125.21.167.153)  41.114 ms  40.001 ms  39.457 ms
 5  203.208.190.65 (203.208.190.65)  120.340 ms  71.384 ms  71.346 ms
 6  ge-0-1-0-0.sngtp-dr1.ix.singtel.com (203.208.149.158)  71.493 ms ge-0-1-2-0.sngtp-dr1.ix.singtel.com (203.208.149.210)  71.183 ms ge-0-1-0-0.sngtp-dr1.ix.singtel.com (203.208.149.158)  71.739 ms
 7  ge-0-0-0-0.sngtp-ar3.ix.singtel.com (203.208.182.2)  80.917 ms ge-2-0-0-0.sngtp-ar3.ix.singtel.com (203.208.183.20)  71.550 ms ge-1-0-0-0.sngtp-ar3.ix.singtel.com (203.208.182.6)  71.534 ms
 8  203.208.151.26 (203.208.151.26)  141.716 ms 203.208.145.190 (203.208.145.190)  134.740 ms 203.208.151.26 (203.208.151.26)  142.453 ms
 9  219.158.3.225 (219.158.3.225)  138.774 ms  157.205 ms  157.123 ms
10  219.158.4.69 (219.158.4.69)  156.865 ms  157.044 ms  156.845 ms
11  202.96.12.62 (202.96.12.62)  157.109 ms  160.294 ms  159.805 ms
12  61.148.3.58 (61.148.3.58)  159.521 ms  178.088 ms  160.004 ms
     MPLS Label=33 CoS=5 TTL=1 S=0
13  202.106.48.18 (202.106.48.18)  199.730 ms  181.263 ms  181.300 ms
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
```

mapreduce program:-

public class TraceRouteDataCleaning {

```
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String userArgs[] = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (userArgs.length < 2) {
        System.out.println("Usage: hadoop jar jarfilename mainclass input output");
        System.exit(1);
    }       
    Job job = new Job(conf, "cleaning trace route data");
    job.setJarByClass(TraceRouteDataCleaning.class);        
    job.setMapperClass(TraceRouteMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(TraceRouteReducer.class);       
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(userArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(userArgs[1]));     
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}   
public static class TraceRouteMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{        
    StringBuilder emitValue = null;
    StringBuilder emitKey = null;
    Text kword = new Text();
    Text vword = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws InterruptedException, IOException
     {
         // String[] cleanData;
         String lines = value.toString();   
         //deleting ms in RTT time data  
         lines = lines.replace(" ms", "");               
         String[] data = lines.split(" ");          
         emitValue = new StringBuilder(1024);
         emitKey = new StringBuilder(1024);

            if (data.length == 6) {                     
                emitKey.append(data[0]);
                emitValue.append(data[1]).append("\t").append(data[2]).append("\t").append(data[3]).append("\t").append(data[4]).append("\t").append(data[5]);
                kword.set(emitKey.toString());
                vword.set(emitValue.toString());                            
                context.write(kword, vword);                    
            }               
     }              
}   

public static class TraceRouteReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{
    Text vword = new Text();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        context.write(key,vword);           
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your split string is a single space, but it looks like your data has multiple spaces separating many fields.

Comment: @JeremyBeard:- Yes, thats why i split by space in map method.

Comment: In above code, output is only first line is coming. other lines are not coming.

Comment: You are not aggregating by key in your reducer, you have unique keys ? you can remove the reducer class and output should be 30 lines or iterate over list of values for each key in your reducer and output key and value ( concatenate for each key )

Comment: @Prahalad:- i have tried without reducer class also. Output is only the first line. with reducer also there is no change in output. Expected output is first 13 lines.

Answer (score 0):

first thing  your reducer classs should below based on your requirement.if your key is not emitting multiple texts then opt first reducer or else choose second one.

```
public static class TraceRouteReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{
Text vword = new Text();
public void reduce(Text key, Text values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    vword=values;

    /*
 for (Iterator iterator = values.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

    vword.set(iterator.next().toString());
    System.out.println("printing " +vword.toString());

}*/

    context.write(key,vword);           


}
 }

   ----------or------------

public static class TraceRouteReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{
Text vword = new Text();
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

   for (Iterator iterator = values.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

    vword.set(iterator.next().toString());
    context.write(key,vword);  


}          


}
}


second in your mapper you are splitting based on space.but not feasible as of my knowledge. split based on   "\\s+"  regular expression.

   String[] data = lines.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Mapper output itself is not giving full result. It is giving only the first line of the data, remaining data is not visible in that.

Comment: In your mapper code give like  if(data.length>5)..split based on regex..I mentioned above